# DHCP Server/Client using TCP in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I need some information concerning on a small project I've been given.
I have little experience in network programming.

"Simulate a DHCP Server/client using TCP (in java)

A client will simulate that it is connecting to a DHCP server. It will send its MAC Address and in return receive an IP Address. The server will have to maintain a list of IP Addresses allocated. IP addresses are allocated for a leased time, which can be set on the server. When the lease time is over, the server will allocate another IP Address to the client. The project will have to be implemented using multithreading

Is it really possible to write it in TCP? As far as i know, tcp doesn't support broadcast and dhcp server uses UDP normally.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a school project... Also sounds like you're over thinking it. I think you can ignore DHCP and just follow the specs. Client connects -> sends "MAC." Server returns an "IP" and sets a lease timer. Lease timer expires, and a new "IP" is sent. I put those in quotes because I'm sure you're not literally expected to implement DHCP from scratch.

Comment: "simulate" is a key word. What you need to do is to implement protocol and client/server for it. Just go through specification of the exercise and replace every occurrence of "MAC address" with "client-specific unique key", and every occurrence of "IP address" with "value from pre-defined pool of values".